# Como fazer deploy com Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, git, deploy, wordpress-theme

Quero aumentar a agilidade dos meus projetos feitos com `Wordpress`. Geralmente utilizo o `git` apenas nos temas. Quando está tudo pronto, subo o tema da forma tradicional, por FTP. Claro, eu sei que está errado e que não é assim a forma correta de proceder.

A minha dúvida é: eu devo versionar todo o código do `Wordpress` e fazer o deploy da mesma maneira que eu faço com `Ruby on Rails` ou fazer só o versionamento do tema mas fazer um deploy automatizado dele individualmente?

A minha dúvida é porque o time de desenvolvimento do `Wordpress` lança atualizações com uma certa frequência... e é sempre aconselhável manter ele atualizado. Como eu iria lidar com isso? Toda vez que uma atualização for lançada eu vou ter que fazer um novo deploy com a nova versão pra todos os meus clientes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A primeira coisa que você precisa ter em mente é: ***Preciso versionar o*** `core` ***do*** [wordpress](/questions/tagged/wordpress)***?***

Você não terá problemas com o *deploy*, visto que irá tratar o projeto como um *todo*. Para isso, tenha em mente que qualquer atualização automática ou edição através do *file editor* do WordPress podem trazer conflitos na estrutura de [versionamento](/questions/tagged/versionamento). Para evitar estes conflitos, existem configurações que podem ser realizadas para evitar isso:

1. **Desabilitando o Editor de Plugin e Tema:**

Exemplo: `define( 'DISALLOW_FILE_EDIT', true );`

2. **Desabilitando atualizações automáticas:**

Exemplo: `define( 'WP_AUTO_UPDATE_CORE', false );`

Também pode ser necessário adicionar `filter` para evitar atualização de `plugin` ou temas:

```
add_filter( 'auto_update_plugin', '__return_false' );
add_filter( 'auto_update_theme', '__return_false' );
```

3. **Crie uma *branch* para cada atualização do core:**

Como as atualizações não serão realizadas de forma automática, a cada atualização você deverá fazer isso manualmente (sim, isso mesmo). Particularmente acho isso custoso para o processo.

4. **Alguns arquivos devem estar no** `.gitignore`**:**

Arquivos como `wp-config.php`, e os diretórios de `uploads` e `upgrade` devem estar fora do escopo de versionamento.

5. **Fique atento às configurações locais:**

Tendo mais de um ambiente, existe uma preocupação maior com relação às variáveis de ambiente que estarão no `wp-config.php`.

> Todas essas e outras dicas eu encontrei neste artigo (muito interessante):
>   [Keeping WordPress Under [Version] Control with Git](http://stevegrunwell.github.io/wordpress-git/)

Sobre o *deploy* em si, a resposta do @IvanFerrer tem um link com maiores informações.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode fazer isso através de uma conta online, com o [GitHub](http://github.com) ou o [BitBucket](http://bitbucket.org). [Este vídeo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TF7Vvk0s86g) orienta como fazer.

Primeiro crie o versionamento do seu projeto na sua máquina e depois clone seu projeto no servidor remoto:

`git clone user@servidor:/caminho/para/o/repositorio`

Se você não clonou um repositório existente e quer conectar seu repositório a um servidor remoto, você deve adicioná-lo com:

`git remote add origin http://seu-endereco-repositorio.git`

Depois de ter seu repositório lançado, para fazer o deploy automaticamente siga [esse tutorial](https://serverpilot.io/community/articles/how-to-automatically-deploy-a-git-repo-from-bitbucket.html).

Comment: Sim sim...
Mas e quanto às atualizações do core? Por exemplo. Tenho meu repositório lá na produção, lindão e funcional. Sai uma atualização do core. Meu cliente vai lá e clica pra atualizar. Vai ocorrer alterações em alguns arquivos do core, ainda que poucas. Se eu tentar fazer deploy automaticamente dando pull no meu repositório, vai dar problema pois as alterações não foram commitadas. A minha dúvida maior é essa.  Com muitos clientes é inviável sair de site em site verificando se tem atualizações não commitadas :/

Comment: Pode adicionar essas configurações no teu .gitignore  (https://gist.github.com/epeli/4c34d665d26cd8d8ea83d7d06b423e66)